# mpg123 lib For Android 4.0

Tags: android, video

i am Creating Application Of music pitch change using NDK

does Anybody Have Updated mpg123 lib For android?

It is Nice Working on android 2.3
But,
mpg123 lib is Not Working with android 4.0 or higher version

Comment: what problem u are setting on Android 4.0?

Comment: i think u are getting Can't open default sound device! error?